# Golang: How to cross compile on Linux for Windows

Tags: linux, go, gcc, cross-compiling

How do I cross compile a Go project on Linux to generate an executable for running on Windows?

Answer (score 71):

To build from Linux to Windows, you need to set the environment variables `GOOS` to `Windows` and `GOARCH` to `amd64`.

On Bash or ZSH:

```
% GOOS=windows GOARCH=amd64 go build
```

- For more details see: https://dave.cheney.net/2015/08/22/cross-compilation-with-go-1-5
- A description of possible values for GOOS and GOARCH is available here: https://golang.org/doc/install/source#environment

If your package requires `CGO` then you need to use the mingw-w64 compiler:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-multilib
sudo apt-get install gcc-mingw-w64

GOOS=windows GOARCH=386 \
  CGO_ENABLED=1 CXX=i686-w64-mingw32-g++ CC=i686-w64-mingw32-gcc \
  go build
```

Comment: Just wanted to clarify that (at least now) you only need to specify GOOS, the GOARCH can be the same as what you're using.  That said, it's worth noting that GOOS is case-sensitive, I'd initially tried setting `GOOS=Windows` and that did not have any impact, until I noticed you had it as `GOOS=windows`.

Comment: Why with `CGO` the GOARCH is `386`? What if I want to build it for `amd64`?

Comment: I got ""i686-w64-mingw32-g++": executable file not found in $PATH"

Comment: I suppose you can use `x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc` and `x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++` for `amd64`

Answer (score 7):

## Introduction

During your production process you may want to build your go program to support a windows architecture, but this is not always easy but here's a guide to help you building your go program for windows

### CGO

Cgo is an element of go that allow Go packages to call C code.

But whether you're using CGO or not is not as easy as "did I called C code?" because while you may not have called C code in you Go program, a package that you're using probably does.

To figure it out the easiest thing is to try without and if it's not working try the second option. (But you can also try [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/golang/comments/655kax/how_to_figure_out_whats_using_cgo/) if you want to)

## If you don't need CGO

if you don't need CGO, building your go program to another platform is pretty easy as go natively support cross-platform compiling.
all you need to do is this:

x64

```bash
#Compile your go program to the windows x64 platform 
env GOOS=windows GOARCH=amd64 go build package-import-path
```

x32

```bash
#Compile your go program to the windows x32 platform 
env GOOS=windows GOARCH=386 go build package-import-path
```

Tip: Since go natively support cross compiling, you can easily build your program to other platform as well, further reading [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-build-go-executables-for-multiple-platforms-on-ubuntu-16-04)

## If you need CGO

if you need CGO, building your program will be a little bit more complicated since C doesn't support native cross-platform compiling..
But don't worry! It is still pretty easy using the [MinGW64](https://www.mingw-w64.org/) project.

### Requirements

Since we will be using mingw64 to build our project, we'll need to make sure mingw is installed.
If it's not here's how you can install it:

#### Ubuntu

On ubuntu simply run:

```bash
sudo apt-get install gcc-mingw-w64
```

#### Fedora

On fedora simply run:

```bash
sudo dnf install mingw64-gcc
```

### Build

Now that we met the requirements, we can now build our project

#### For windows x64 architecture

To build your program on a windows x64 architecture run:

```bash
GOOS=windows GOARCH=amd64 CGO_ENABLED=1 CXX=x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ CC=x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc go build package-import-path
```

#### For windows x32 architecture

To build your program on a windows x32 architecture run:

```bash
GOOS=windows GOARCH=386 CGO_ENABLED=1 CXX=i686-w64-mingw32-g++ CC=i686-w64-mingw32-gcc go build package-import-path
```

Comment: Tried this approach but ended up with this error: `/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: cannot find -lstdc++`. Any idea what could this mean?

Comment: Hi! It either looks like a broken mingw installation or some missing dependencies. If you have multiple conflicting mingw installation try uninstalling them all and only install one. If reinstalling it doesn't work, you can try running  `dnf provides lstdc++.so` and installing a package providing it. (I'm assuming you're using Fedora)

Comment: You may want to try using `-lstdc++.so` as an argument if it still doesn't works.